# Meteor bundle error on startup

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have an issue with meteor bundle. I try to start bundle with foreverjs but get error

root@ip-172-31-0-83:/home/ubuntu/bundle# cat ../logs/forever.log

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

I tried install fibers via npm

```
npm install fibers -g
```

,also I've tried install in local meteor node_modules dir.

But unfortunately error stays.

Version of meteor is 0.9.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure to install Fibers has changed in 0.9.x+

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/):

```
cd bundle
cd programs/server
npm install
```

Also, the correct setup instructions (for a bundle built by any version of Meteor) can be found in the bundle's `README` file.